# Pokemong GO Stuck at loading screen with spinning white pokeball

Tags: pokemon-go, android

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE! 
When I login with Google account the screen goes white with spinning white pokeball under the Pokemon GO logo. Seriously, I dont know what to do. I made other account with Pokemon trainer and it works fine. But I will be grateful for any solution to get back to my previous account because I had there many pokemons.

[image]

Comment: Rather than just saying "this is not a duplicate", please explain why it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

- Kill app (I mean *kill*, don't just close it)
- Start app
- Log in
- Repeat, if necessary
- Clear cache (Android), if it doesn't work after a few tries

This should do after one or two tries. At least it works for me. Always*.

`*` *Unless the servers are having issues. There is no way you can nicely ask the servers to let you in.*

Comment: From a suggested edit: "Basically, go to Settings --> Data Usage --> Google Services --> make sure 'Restrict background data' is unticked.

The reason why your PTC account worked and your Google account didn't was because background data was restricted for Google Serivces, so Pokemon Go is trying to access Google Services in the background but it is restricted. Please let me know if it works!!!"

Comment: Unticking 'Restrict background data' seems to have worked for me right now! Nothing else has. Which is strange because if you're launching the app, it should not be considered "background data". This will probably also increase data usage as background apps now can use it at will. Not ideal but a short term workaround to a very frustrating bug.